# Prevent firestore triggers when serving firebase functions locally

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I am new to Firebase, I setup a project and using nodejs + nestjs

- I have a https trigger function that adds record to Firestore
- I have a Firestore document `onCreate` trigger, to duplicate data to another collection

Then I try to run Firebase locally by running `npm run serve` which is calling `firebase serve --only functions`

Then I can access the https function via postman app.

First problem is Firestore `onCreate` trigger is not fired locally when I call my local https function.

Second problem is Firestore `onCreate` trigger is run on server and I can see running logs, which means in development time, some buggy bad code could be running on server and that code might corrupt data (while the good code is under development and bugs are fixing on my local)

So my question is, how usually people do development on their local and testing?

Answer (score 2):

`firebase serve --only functions` only emulates HTTPS functions.

`firebase experimental:functions:shell` works with everything else, but you have to construct stub data to send to it.

See the documentation for more information:

- [Run Functions Locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator)
- [Unit testing functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing)

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've already read that, I am running https locally,the problem is when I emulate https locally (which writes to firestore), firestore trigger on server will fire

Comment: Right, you can expect that to happen.  All writes that could trigger a deployed function will actually trigger that function.  You have to undeploy the function to stop that.